# Bootstrap rule and my class doesn't cooperate

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my page, I use bootstrap. I created table and it has 3 classes, check it:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I use code jQuery. This code added class highlight. Class highlight:

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When table has only one class: "table" it's working. 
But I must have table-striped and table-bordered. When it is, highlight is working only with even numbers. How can I fix that?

Comment: You want to highlight odd numbers?

Comment: I want to highlight both. It's highlighting table rows.

Comment: `.highlight tr td` instead `.highlight` in your **css** - http://jsfiddle.net/pujsghe6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a css specificity issue.

Bootstrap applies the alternating row class like this:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)
```

You need to be as specific as that or more.

Row highlight example:

```
.table>tbody>tr.highlight>td {
    // change your background color here
}
```

Cell highlight example:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td.highlight {
    // change your background color here
}
```

**Note:**  I'm assuming you want to highlight some rows or cells, not the entire table.

Comment: You made it. Second example at your post is an answer for question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
In your jQuery code, instead of `.highlight` use `.highlight > tbody > tr`

```
.highlight > tbody > tr {
   background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that one is good. This code worked as well, just not able to see your jQuery code. Screenshot posted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem: every time you add `highlight` with jQuery to your `table` nothing happens (or not all table raws become orange).

Probably if the `background-color` of the table isn't set on `table` but on `td`.

Try to change simply your `CSS` selector:

```
.highlight{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

to

```
.highlight tr td{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Watch this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pujsghe6/